# Java GregorianCalendar Fields

Tags: java, calendar

I try to convert a String to GregorianCalendar, and then check it. 
Below, I post my codes. I really confuse that why the fields seem wrong.
Thanks a lot for help.

```
public class test{

    private static final ArrayList<String> MONTH_OF_YEAR = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList( "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", 
          "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"));

    static GregorianCalendar date;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String t = "28-Mar-2099 11294.94 11279.65";
        String[] splitStr = t.split(" ");

        System.out.println(splitStr[0]);

        date = ConvertToDate(splitStr[0]);
        System.out.println(date.getTime());

        System.out.println(date.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        System.out.println(date.MONTH);
        System.out.println(date.YEAR);

    }


    private static GregorianCalendar ConvertToDate(String dt){
        String[] splitStr = dt.split("-");
        if(splitStr.length != 3){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        int dayOfMonth = Integer.parseInt(splitStr[0]);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(splitStr[2]);
        int month = MONTH_OF_YEAR.indexOf(splitStr[1]);
        if(month < 0 || month > 11){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return new GregorianCalendar(year, month, dayOfMonth);
    }
}
```

And the outputs are like these:

```
28-Mar-2099
Sat Mar 28 00:00:00 PDT 2099
5
2
1
```

Could anyone help me explain why that the fields don't match the date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These:

```
System.out.println(date.DAY_OF_MONTH);
System.out.println(date.MONTH);
System.out.println(date.YEAR);
```

Should be:

```
System.out.println(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
System.out.println(date.get(Calendar.MONTH));
System.out.println(date.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

(And then remember that `Calendar.MONTH` is 0-based.)

The `DAY_OF_MONTH` etc values are constants, basically indicating which field you want to fetch. The calendar API is fundamentally pretty awful, unfortunately :( If you can possibly use Joda Time or the Java 8 `java.time` API instead, they're both much better.

Also note that there's really no need to write your own calendar parsing code - it already exists with `SimpleDateFormat` etc.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse(
    "28-Mar-2099 11294.94 11279.65".split( " " )[0] ,        // Extract the part of the input text we care about.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uuuu" , Locale.US ) // Specify formatting pattern to match input. The `Locale` determines human language and cultural norms needed for parsing.
).getYear() // .getMonthValue() .getDayOfMonth()             // Interrogate for the parts of the date you desire.
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes that supplanted the troublesome old date-time classes. The `GregorianCalendar` class was replaced by `ZonedDateTime`.

You want a date-only value, without a time-of-day and without a time zone. So use `LocalDate`.

Extract the part of the input we care about.

```
String[] pieces = "28-Mar-2099 11294.94 11279.65".split( " " );
String input = pieces[0] ;
```

Define a formatting pattern to match that input. By the way, when possible, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for exchanging date-time values whenever possible rather than format encountered here.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uuuu" , Locale.US ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Extract any part of the date.

```
int year = ld.getYear() ;
Month month = ld.getMonth() ;  // An enum object from `Month` enum class.
int monthNumber = ld.getMonthValue() ;
int dayOfMonth = ld.getDayOfMonth() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).